# multiline uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

How to set a multiline as title of a `UIButton` in iPhone programming ?

Comment: Agree this should be closed as a dupe. Raju - please can you try searching rather than just posting new questions. You are wasting everyone elses time. It might also help the general goodwill if you marked a few of the questions you asked as answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add multi-line text to a UIButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add multi-line text to a UIButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton)

Answer (score 7):

```
someButton.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

Be sure to try to get in the habit of consulting the documentation before posting a question. Apple's documentation is pretty comprehensive, and things like this generally get covered.

Comment: "Be sure to try to get in the habit of consulting the documentation before posting a question."

Comment: UIButton's `lineBreakMode` property is deprecated in iOS 3.0.  Use `someButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode =` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Hi,

There is a property of UIButton called lineBreakMode which will allow you to add multiline titles. The two main things I would set it to are UILineBreakModeWordWrap or UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap.

UILineBreakModeWordWrap wraps the last word and UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap wraps at the lastcharcter.

looks like: `instanceOfUIButton.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;`

or `instanceOfUIButton.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;`

hope that's what your after

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use subviews.

```
someButton.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

this is the right way to do this. There is a tutorial on this for the German community!

http://bedifferently.wordpress.com/2011/11/16/uibutton-bearbeite-den-titel-teil-1/

Comment: Please do more than just post a link; summarize the link so that this answer can stand on its own in case that link breaks.

Answer (score -2):

UIButton doesn't display multiple lines. The way to make it do so is to addSubview a UILabel to the button