# UIButton : Multiline text

Tags: iphone, uibutton

What would be the best way to implement a multiline text on a UIButton for iPhone SDK 3.2?

Thanks!
Nicolas.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add multi-line text to a UIButton?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton)

Comment: The first, best way is to click on the search field in the top-right corner of the Stack Overflow page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding newline characters (`\n`) to your title text doesn't work, you could try adding a `UILabel` with an appropriate `numberOfLines` as a subview of the button.

Comment: Let me verify and I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: I found it guys. Keep it simple. As you know, there is a UILabel in the button. So, you can set the numberOfLines to 0 and textAlignment to UITextAlignmentCenter for the label. It will do the job.