# Programmatically perform an action on UILabel touchUpInside?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

I have a bunch of UILabels that I add through code and I want to perform a specific action for each if the user's finger touches up inside (much like UIButton's touchUpInside in IB). What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use UIButton instead of UILabel.  A custom UIButton has no border and can look like a plain label, but handles the event tracking for you.

Otherwise, you must derive from UILabel and implement the UIResponder calls for touch handling.

Comment: To make a button behave more like a lable, you may need multi-line text with wrapping in a button. See this answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton

Comment: Note that UIButton doesn't work well with text wrapping and sometimes a UILabel is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can use UITapGestureRecognizer to perform action over the label Fields.

Set the number of taps and touches on the UITapGestureRecognizer object.

```
[oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[oneFingerTwoTaps setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
```

set user interaction of label field like

```
labelField.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

then add target method over the

```
UITapGestureRecognizer object.
```