# On iOS, a UIButton can use addTarget -- what about UILabel?

Tags: ios, uilabel

On iOS, a `UIButton` can use `addTarget` to specify a method to call when the button is tapped on, but what about `UILabel`, is there something similar, or is the only option using `UITapGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: The question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269385/programmatically-perform-an-action-on-uilabel-touchupinside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` is a method of UIControl class.
UIButton is a subclass of UIControl but not UILabel. So yes a tap gesture is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169798/handling-touch-event-in-uilabel-and-hooking-it-up-to-an-ibaction) for the answer.

> UILabel inherits from UIView which inherits from UIResponder. All UIresponder objects can handle touch events.

Comment: does that mean we have to define a new class that subclasses `UILabel` and then implement `touchesBegan`?

Comment: Nope! Just add code to your view controller. When following the instructions on the selected answer in the above link, note that its comments are helpful too.

Comment: In particular, the bit about matching touch.view to your IBOutlet.