# Center text in a UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do you center the text inside a UILabel?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

The Code is

```
[yourLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

or (of course) the Obj-C 2.0 Dot-Syntax

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

---

For iOS 6 (and higher) you should use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` instead of `UITextAlignmentCenter`:

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton/12776945#12776945)

And if you want backward compatibiliy to iOS 5 also you can do this,

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
# define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
# define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif
```

**Swift 3**

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: Or with a little less bracket soup: yourLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

Comment: UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated after iOS 6.0. Now use NSTextAlignmentCenter.

Comment: Also note that if you call [yourLabel sizeToFit] after setting the textAlignment, it will end up left-justified and ignore the textAlignment property.

Answer (score 27):

This is depreciated now in iOS6.

You should use:

```
yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Answer (score 6):

Besides using code, as Henrik suggested, you can also set the appropriate property in Interface Builder.

Comment: How?  Content Mode doesn't work.  Niether does Alignment.  So what in Interface Builder does it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multiline UILabel you should use a NSMutableParagraphStyle

```
   label.numberOfLines = 0
   let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
   paragraphStyle.alignment = .Center

   let attributes : [String : AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15)!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle]

   let attributedText = NSAttributedString.init(string: subTitleText, attributes: attributes)
   label.attributedText = attributedText
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
labelName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following code:

```
lblObject.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

UITextAlignmentCenter is deprecated since NSTextAlignmentCenter since iOS 6.0. You should use NSTextAlignmentCenter instead:

```
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 10.2.1 use:

```
UIlabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using UIBUILDER (Swift 4)** (EZ!)

Center UILabel text most easily using the "Alignment" property inside the label's Attributes Inspector. (fig. 1)

[image: "Figure 1"]