# starting text in uitextview from center both horizontally and vertically

Tags: iphone

I want to begin text entered into UItextview from center both horizontally and vertically, please some one help me.

Comment: refer to this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743904/center-text-in-a-uilabel

Comment: @iamsult alignment problematics for UITextView and UILabel are quite different.

Answer (score 0):

set Alignment as center.for that select the textfield from .xib class and go to the library and in that set Alognment as center.