# UIButton with two lines of text in the title (numberOfLines=2)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uilabel

I'm trying to make a `UIButton` that has two lines of text in its titleLabel. This is the code I'm using:

```
UIButton *titleButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, frame.size.width-100, 100)];
titleButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0];
[titleButton setTitle:@"This text is very long and should get truncated at the end of the second line" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
titleButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
titleButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
[self addSubview:titleButton];
```

When I try this, the text only appears on one line. It seems the only way to achieve more than one line of text in `UIButton.titleLabel` is to set `numberOfLines=0` and use `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`. But this doesn't guarantee the text to be exactly two lines.

Using a plain `UILabel`, however, does work:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, frame.size.width-100, 100)];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0];
titleLabel.text = @"This text is very long and should get truncated at the end of the second line";
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
[self addSubview:titleLabel];
```

Does anyone know how to make the `UIButton` work with two lines? Is the only solution to create a separate `UILabel` to hold the text, and add it as a subview of the button?

Comment: Have you seen this ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton

Comment: Viraj, yes, if you set `numberOfLines=0` and use `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`, you can get multiple lines. The problem with that is it could give more than two lines if the text is too long. I want _exactly_ two lones with an elipses at the end of the second line (if the text is too long).

Comment: Oh, then I guess adding subview may be the only way to go.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

**Updated answer for more recent iOS versions**

Since this is the accepted answer, added @Sean's answer here:

Set these properties on the titleLabel of your button.

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2; // if you want unlimited number of lines put 0
```

Swift 3 and 4:

```
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2 // if you want unlimited number of lines put 0
```

---

**Original answer for an older version of iOS**

If you want 2 lines of text on top of your `UIButton` you should add a `UIlabel` on top of it that does precisely that.

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 10, frame.size.width-100, 100)];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:24.0];
titleLabel.text = @"This text is very long and should get truncated at the end of the second line";
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
[myButton addSubview:titleLabel]; //add label to button instead.
```

---

**Updated for interface builder solution**

Added @Borut Tomazin's answer for a more complete answer.
Updated this part again since the answer of @Borut Tomazin was improved.

You can do this much easier, with no code required. In Interface Builder set `Line Break` on UIButton to `Word Wrap`. Than you can insert multiple lines of title. Just hit `Option + Return` keys to make new line. You will also need to add this to the User Defined Runtime Attribute in Interface Builder:

```
titleLabel.textAlignment Number [1]
```

Comment: `UILineBreakMode` are deprecated, use `NSLineBreakMode` instead of it

Comment: This is unnecessary as of recent iOS versions. See @sean's answer.

Answer (score 146):

You don't need to add a UILabel to the UIButton. That's just extra objects and work.

Set these properties on the titleLabel of your button.

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;//if you want unlimited number of lines put 0
```

Swift:

```
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 2//if you want unlimited number of lines put 0
```

Comment: This is the 2013 and as of today this is the state of the art solution.

Comment: @Blip you can't unfortunately and need to do it in code. Might be worth filing a bug report with Apple requesting this functionality.

Comment: @bpapa Yep I agree, storyboards should be more flexible.

Comment: This works for me, however it breaks the default behaviour of the button's `intrinsicContentSize`, which still returns a height that corresponds to just one line of text. I fixed it by overriding the button's `intrinsicContentSize` where I set the height to be `[self.titleLabel sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(self.titleLabel.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height`.

Comment: @WillVonUllrich because you can only change the accepted answer when it is edited. I added these answers to the accepted one so it will help the people that do not look further then the accepted answer.

Answer (score 88):

You can do this much easier, with no code required. In Interface Builder set `Line Break` on UIButton to `Word Wrap`. Than you can insert multiple lines of title. Just hit `Option + Return` keys to make new line. 
You will also need to add this to the User Defined Runtime Attribute in Interface Builder:

```
titleLabel.textAlignment Number [1]
```

It's that simple. Hope it helps...

Comment: This solution is better (less objects, code) than the currently accepted one, for simple cases.

Comment: You set the exact same properties as you would programmatically so your argument "less objects" is invalid.

Code is maybe less. But it is more readable. Take your pick ;)

Comment: Oh, I was unclear I think. Thanks for trying to clarify. Was not so much concerned with the fact that it is done in IB vs Code. More to do with the fact that you don't need to add an additional label with Borut's solution, and that it also accomplishes the same thing. But yes, both work great. :)

Comment: it's really overwhelming to need to go to code behind for such a basic task.

Comment: You can achieve the same goal 100% codeless by adding the `titleLabel.textAlignment` *User Defined Runtime Attribute* in Interface Builder and set it to *Number* = 1 (NSTextAlignmentCenter's value).

Comment: `UITextAlignmentCenter` is deprecated, use `NSTextAlignmentCenter` instead.

Comment: @BlackTigerX I will add it to mine since the OP is not anywhere to be seen.

Answer (score 21):

```
 button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[button setTitle: @"Line1\nLine2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Perfect one! You don't have to split the `NSString` inside `setTitle`. `WordWrapping`` is doing this for you!

Comment: For me I had to split the string inside the set title. Without that it didn't work

Answer (score 9):

To avoid completely the need to edit code, and thus the need to subclass your view, in Xcode5 and greater you can follow Borut Tomazin suggestion:

> In Interface Builder **(or storyboard)** set Line Break to
>   Word Wrap. Than you can insert multiple lines of title. Just hit
>   <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> keys to make new line.

and then, in the **User Defined Runtime Attributes** you can add

Key path: `titleLabel.textAlignment`
Type: `Number`
Value: `1`

*Note: this may be not completely "future proof" since we are translating the `UITextAlignmentCenter` constant into its numerical value (and that constant may change as new iOS versions are released), but it seems safe in the near future.*

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the needed value directly from Storyboard.
Select the button, go to the identity inspector and add the following key-value pair in the "User defined runtime attributes" section:

[image]