# How do you add multi-line text to a UIButton AND have it's height adjust accordingly?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

I have a table view (row heights are set to automatic), where each cell has a single UIButton (whose top and bottom is constrained to the cell's contentView.top and contentView.bottom, the leading side is fixed to contentView.leading, and the trailing is dynamically set to <= contentView.trailing, dependent upon the length of text). I need the height of the button to grow depending on the amount of text, so that it can show multi-line text if needed.

Now, I have tried various things which seem like they would do the trick. For example, I followed [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831928/uibutton-with-two-lines-of-text-in-the-title-numberoflines-2), which states to set the following:

```
myButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
myButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

This successfully allows the button's titleLabel to become multi-line, but the button is still not adjusting to fit its title label. [See this image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvECU.png).

*Note: I set the button's content insets, but these values seem to have no effect when the text becomes multi-line. Clipping still occurs*

Based on a few other SO questions, I've come to the conclusion that it has something to do with the UIButton's `intrinsicContentSize`, so [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27259333/uibutton-that-resizes-to-fit-its-titlelabel/38140457#38140457) recommended subclassing UIButton and then overriding the `intrinsicContentSize` property...

```
class ResizableButton: UIButton {
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return self.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize
    }

    // Whever the button is changed or needs to layout subviews,
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel!.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

...but when I tried this, I got an [even wonkier result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2Tnz.png). It seems to me that I must not be returning the correct value for the `intrinsicContentSize` property. If this is the case, does anyone know how I can return the correct value to achieve the result I am looking for? Otherwise, if this is not correct, any other suggestions are welcome. I'm also unsure about my current implementation of the `layoutSubviews` method.

*Note: I know I* could *just create a separate UILabel, and handle the multi-line text separately from the UIButton, but I prefer to keep the text within the button itself if this is possible, especially since UIButton's handle selection/deselection animations inherently.*

**UPDATE:** I have tried @valosip's solution. This fixed the content inset issue, but the text is still starting a new line after only a couple letters instead of taking up the full width ([See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUM2C.png)). Any solutions for this? Again, note that I have the trailing constraint of the UIButton to be <= contentView.trailing, but UIButton is clearly not getting anywhere near the trailing edge.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your `intrinsicContentSize` to add the content insets

```
class ResizableButton: UIButton {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        guard let title = titleLabel else {
            return super.intrinsicContentSize
        }
        let size = title.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right, height: size.height + contentEdgeInsets.top + contentEdgeInsets.bottom)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        guard let title = titleLabel else { return }
        titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = title.frame.size.width
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped with the content inset issue, but I'm still having problems with the text starting a new line after only a couple of characters. If you don't mind, please see my update at the bottom of the post for more info.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @Eric Update your question with how you're setting up the buttons (programmatically or storyboard) and show us your constraints.  Based on your second (updated) image, your constraints look wrong.