# How to generate multi-line rather than single line with UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uialertview

This is my code

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Added to Cart" message:@"Some items are added for time being!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"View Cart" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue \n Shopping", nil];
alert.tag = 20;
[alert show];
```

I get output like this:
[image]

I need like this:
[image]

Comment: Strange, your formatting seems correct and if i remember right it should also work. Just in case try using `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Continue\nShopping"]`

Comment: sry i was tried but its not working

Comment: Hmm. I had similiar problem few month ago. It might be that i switched to using UIActionSheet, not sure.

Comment: Check out the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton

Comment: Create custom button and addSubview to alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have manual solution for you. But I think its not a good solution:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Added to Cart" message:@"Some items are added for time being!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"View Cart" otherButtonTitles:@"", nil];

    UILabel *buttonTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(148, 102, 125, 40)];
    buttonTitle.text = @"Continue Shopping";
    buttonTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    buttonTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    buttonTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    buttonTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    buttonTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
    [alert addSubview:buttonTitle];
    alert.tag = 20;
    [buttonTitle release];
    [alert show];
```

You can use it anyway....

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertView` doesn't support multi-line buttons. One option would be to just use "Continue" instead of "Continue Shopping" as the button title, otherwise you'd have to use a custom alert view component, e.g. [CODialog](https://github.com/eaigner/CODialog) (you might have to customize it a bit to allow multi-line buttons, but it should be easy).

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Added to Cart" message:@"Some items are added for time being!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"View Cart" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue \n Shopping", nil];
alert.tag = 20;
[[[alert buttons] objectAtIndex:1] setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[alert show];
```

This code does exactly what you need.
Note, however that

1. `- [UIAlertView buttons]` is undocumented
2. `- [UIButton setLineBreakMode]` is deprecated. You can however, replace it with

   `[button.titleLabel setLineBreakMode]` which is essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to set numbersOfLine property to label on button. But i don`t know will apple aprove that.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Added to Cart" message:@"Some items are added for time being!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"View Cart" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue \n Shopping", nil];
NSArray *subviewsArray = [alert subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in subviewsArray) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            NSArray *btnSubviews = [subview subviews];
            for (UIView *btnSubview in btnSubviews) {
                if ([btnSubview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                    UILabel *title = (UILabel *)btnSubview;
                    title.numberOfLines = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
alert.tag = 20;
[alert show];
[alert release];
```