# UIButton with edge inset does not follow content compression resistance property

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios-autolayout

Content hugging priority =250

content compression resistance priority =750

width =70 priority =500 (for normal text)

left and right edge inset  =3

[image: This is how it looks when left and right edge inset is =3]

if I set left and right edge inset  = 0 and rest of the things as it is

[image: This is how it looks when left and right edge inset is =0]

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800288/autolayout-intrinsic-size-of-uibutton-does-not-include-title-insets

Comment: did you get anything to do it in interface>

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting the title inset, set the content Inset & it will work fine