# Swift button width depends on text length when adding title Insets

Tags: swift, button, layout, swift4

hi i want to resize my button width by text length when adding title right insets

i tried set Constant 100 and Priority 1000 and it work perfect
but when i add image and right insets,

button title show like this

"apple...omputer"

and i tried this

```
button.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
```

and

```
button.sizeToFit()
```

still not work and still show "..." in my button text

and i tried to add width after set button title in viewdidload, but still not working

```
button.frame = CGRect(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, button.frame.width+50, button.frame.height)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Autolayout - intrinsic size of UIButton does not include title insets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800288/autolayout-intrinsic-size-of-uibutton-does-not-include-title-insets)

Comment: Could share a screenshot to understand what's the exact problem?

Comment: hi @Kirow yes, thanks for your help, i solve my question by setting layout at trailing. thanks

Comment: @Ashutosh , thanks , i solve my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Storyboard buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrYDS.png)

[Resizing button because text became larger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Ssf.png)

Please look at screenshots above. You need to set your insets and set right constraints. Autolayout does it for you.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, i set the layout  greate than or equal at button width, now i got it. thans