# Why my UIButton's title is truncated in the middle while using titleEdgeInsets?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Here is my `UIButton` defined like this:

```
private var continueButton: AttributedButton = {
    let button = AttributedButton()
    button.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 20, bottom: 6, right: 20)
    button.setTitle("game.continue".localized.uppercased(), for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.cornerRadius = 10
    return button
}()
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The solution described here worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30319448

Answer (score 17):

Use `contentEdgeInsets` property instead of `titleEdgeInsets`

Comment: Yes but there is no padding between the button and the text anymore.