# UIButton with multi-line titleLabel in InterfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, interface-builder

I've been wondering, is there a nice way to make `UIButtons` with multi-line `titleLabel` in Interface Builder? I've found none and puttin a separate `UILabel` on top of each button and tracking it's color on press and other events is not very straightforward.

Maybe there are better alternatives done in code if there's no such way in IB?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Code:**

To allow multiple line you can use:

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[button setTitle: @"Line1\nLine2" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

In **iOS 6**, `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` and `UITextAlignmentCenter` are deprecated, so use:

```
button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

**Interface Builder:**

- In interface builder select *UIButton*
- on the right side Utilities pane under *Attributes Inspector*, you'll see an option for *Line Break*
- Choose *Word Wrap*

Comment: @AsenKasimov what's your problem? The original answer/question has nothing to do with Storyboards

Comment: The problem is that the question which I think is the same as the original contains more answers and during the years more info was added. Like this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/33255117/466577

Answer (score 4):

You can do solely in Interface Builder a couple ways.

- First by simply setting the wrap feature. This offers limited customizability though.
- For more customizability, change the "Plain Text" to "Attributed Text" and then you can do most things without any code.

Answer (score 3):

In the case you are using only plain XCode 9.4:

Set Line Break to any option (to enable numberOfLines) in the Attributes inspector:

[image: The first step in XCode]

Then you can set KeyPath as

```
titleLabel.numberOfLines
```

in the Identity inspector:

[image: The second step in XCode]

Comment: Wow, that's a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention if one does not want word wrap but still want to achieve multi line title on a UIButton it can be done by setting lineBreakMode before numberOfLines,
This is because lineBreakMode seems to cancel out numberOfLines set hence we are doing it in this order.

Swift:

> button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
>
> button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
>
> button.setTitle(myTitle, for: UIControlState.normal)