# NSMutableAttributedString not appending in IOS 13 works well in iOS 12 or below

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutableattributedstring

Below code works well in iOS 12 or below, but fails to append in iOS 13, as it prints only `First Line` and fails to print `Extra Text`.

```
    let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()                                                                 
    formattedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "First Line\n" ,
                                                          attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]))
    formattedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Extra Text", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]))
    self.setAttributedTitle(formattedString, for: .normal)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? How to you print it?

Comment: I used word 'printing' for example .. I'm assigning it to a button as  `self.setAttributedTitle`..   Any Solution for NSMutableAttributedString() ?

Comment: It's probably an issue with the new line character. See if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton

Comment: There is a difference because it's applied to a UIButton and not. Does it work on a UILabel/UITextView? If yes, the issue is with UIButton. Update your question with theses info, adding then a tag UIButton if that's the case might help, and that's not only `NSMutableAttributedString` issue.

Comment: Thanks all.. works after I added these lines
 `self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
            self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
            self.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping;
            self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2;
            let formattedString = NSMutableAttributedString()`